# Styles via JavaScript quicker then using CSS3 sheet, because less code?

Tags: javascript, css, file

Consider having two files **x.js** and **x1.html**.  Is it quicker to execute writing your styles(the same amount of bytes only different files) via only **x.js** not **x3.css** file?
Should I use only **x.js** for writing styles or **x3.css**, which file is faster?

Comment: `seemingly redundant x3.css file` - it's only redundant if you write your CSS in JS.

Answer (score 1):

So so, depend what you necessitie, because 100kb of CSS don't has the same cost of 100kb of JS. If we want to be fast at JavaScript, we have to download it, parse it, compile it, and execute it quickly.

If you spend a long time parsing and compiling script in a JavaScript engine, that delays how soon a user can interact with your experience.

There are a article the Addy Osmani explain every point about perfomance, if you need take a look: https://medium.com/@addyosmani/the-cost-of-javascript-in-2018-7d8950fbb5d4